# Is there a "correct" way to create a button using Dojo 1.9.1?

Tags: dojo, onclick

I want to create a button with Dojo that upon clicking, does dome database quering. I am using Dojo 1.9.1. My only partial success is with

`<button data-dojo-Type="dijit/form/Button" type="Button" onClick="FunctionCall()">Button Name</button>`

(By partial success, I mean it made it to the function in the debugger, beyond that is a whole other can of worms)

I have tried the method described in dijit/form/Button reference guide via the declarative example, but the button does nothing except hang out and look pretty.

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Click me too!
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
        FunctionCall();
    </script>
</button>
```

I also tried the Hello World style guide from a dojo tutorial with no success.

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Click me too!
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
        FunctionCall();
    </script>
</button>
```

Is my first method of calling a function using this dojo button consider correct/acceptable/proper? Or are one of the tutorial methods prefered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my first method of calling a function using this dojo button consider correct/acceptable/proper?

Short answer, yes, but it might not be what you want to do moving forward, as it's not "the dojo way".

If you *do* want to use the `dojo/method` method, I believe you need to set `parseOnLoad` to true in your dojo config. [See this working fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/S3nXf/).

Answer (score 0):

To see how you can create a button in good dojo have a look here;-)

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Button.html#dijit-form-button

There's discribed how to create a button declarativ or programmaticale.

Regards, Miriam